# How do I run a AWS Lambda function to let me know that CloudFormation has completed the entire stack creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I would like to make an automated call to a custom program API as soon as CloudFormation has completed the entire stack creation (deployment of instances, setup of VPC, Puppet scripts, etc.).

What is the correct way to go about this?

After some research, it seems a good option would be to launch an AWS Lambda function triggered by the event that stack creation has been completed successfully, but I have no idea how to approach this.

Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SDK or CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provision and coordinate a lot of what you're talking about (setup of VPC, etc.) with CloudFormation, the **DependsOn** attribute and nested CloudFormation stacks. This way you can order the execution of the CloudFormation stacks so that, for example, your VPC is created first followed by launching your EC2 instance(s) followed by the deployment of the software on the instance(s).

You can also coordinate the execution of the other behavior you mentioned (deployment [on] instances, [calling] Puppet scripts, etc.) using **AWS::CloudFormation::Init**. This way, you can call out to your Puppet scripts from your EC2 instance within the CloudFormation template. The actual execution of your Puppet scripts occurs on the EC2 instance(s).

If you want to see an example of calling out to a configuration management tool from CloudFormation (in this case, we're using Chef Solo), see [app-instance.json](https://github.com/stelligent/dromedary/blob/master/pipeline/cfn/app-instance.json#LL77-LL180).
If you'd like to see an example of using nested stacks, see [dromedary-master.json](https://github.com/stelligent/dromedary/blob/master/pipeline/cfn/dromedary-master.json#LL1240-LL1258).

There's also some examples of using Lambda on our blog as well (Stelligent), but it doesn't seem like you need to use Lambda in this case based on the problem you're trying to solve.

P.S. You don't *have* to use nested stacks either, but it can make things a little cleaner. But, you *do* want to control the creation order of the resources so the DependsOn attribute will help you in doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, how do I ensure the scripts only run once everything has been completely and successfully set up? I have had a problem before, where when I try to mount a partition to /dev/xvdf using scripts in **AWS::CloudFormation::Init**, the location does not exist, but as soon as I can log in, the location exists and the command executes perfectly.

Comment: So, I have found the solution to the mounting problem, here: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/725628/unable-to-mount-ebs-drives-to-an-ubuntu-box-using-aws-cloudformation-userdata-n). However, is there a way to know that CloudFormation has completed all tasks completely and successfully? I was thinking of using Amazon SNS and then subscribing to the CREATE_COMPLETE event, does this seem like a viable option?

Comment: @cameronliam Glad you got the answer to your specific mounting issue. For future consideration, you might also want to look at [Use a CreationPolicy to Wait for On-Instance Configurations](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3CISOFP98TS56/Use-a-CreationPolicy-to-Wait-for-On-Instance-Configurations) to ensure resources are created on an instance prior to performing other actions. Note the use of `"/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init ",` and `"/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",`

Comment: @cameronliam Yes, you can use an Amazon SNS topic and subscribe to an email or other endpoint. I'm not sure if you can subscribe to a specific event like CREATE_COMPLETE, though. If you can, I'd use it too! I do use SNS to get notified of CloudFormation events but it sends *everything*. In any case, when executing your CloudFormation stack, you'd type something like: `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name MyStackName --template-url YOURTEMPLATEURL --region REGION --disable-rollback --capabilities="CAPABILITY_IAM" --notification-arns "arn:aws:sns:REGION:YOURACCOUNTID:YOURSNSTOPIC"`

Comment: Thanks again! Getting very close to solving my problem. One last thing, the reason I want to make the POST is to inform the API endpoint that the instance has been successfully created and then provide it with the Public IP (and likely more information) of that instance, is there any way to facilitate this using SNS? Or do I need a different approach?